# Simplification of an expression involving the dilogarithm with complex argument

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, polylogarithm

Do you think there is a way to get a nice form of the expression below

$$\Im{\left( \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4 i}{5}\right)- \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4 i}{5}\right)+ \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{4}{5}-\frac{3 i}{5}\right)- \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{4}{5}+\frac{3 i}{5}\right)\right)}$$

and if possible to get rid of dilogarithm entirely? Some hints, clues, suggestions?

Comment: Noting that each of the dilog arguments have unit magnitude, we can immediately write this as a sum of four Clausen functions. Symmetries and the duplication formula can reduce this to a sum of two Clausen functions, but I haven't found a way to simplify it beyond that. I find $S=\frac12\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(2a\right)}-2\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{(\pi/2+a)}$, where $a=\arctan{\frac43}$.

Comment: @DavidH (+1) good job! I'll also think of this way and see if it can be simplified further.